# Should answers promoting questionable legality be deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Recent [this answer](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/2589/142) was flagged for deletion due to promoting practices of questionable legality/morality. For now I have left the answer as is, with a suggestion to downvote and/or comment if you feel the need to do so.

Technically the answer does address the question, while bringing the reader's morality into question. There are two points of view on this:

1. Information is information. It is the reader's prerogative to decide whether or not to act on the advice.
2. If something is considered illegal or immoral, we as a community should take a hard stance that such answers (and questions) are considered unacceptable and will be deleted.

Please respond below with your thoughts.

***UPDATE:***

We have 1 answer with 3+1 upvotes (+1 for the person who actually provided the answer, as you would have to assume they agree with their own answer) and 1 downvote. This is not a large sampling from the community, but it is all we have for those who care enough to provide input on the issue. So 80% think we should delete answers that bring legality/morality into question and 20% think we shouldn't. Would a compromise of converting such answers to comments be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 7):

I would be inclined to let the answer go, unless a *competent legal authority* was able to determine that the practices contained in the answer were clearly illegal. There is a tremendous amount of misinformation, speculation, rumor, unsubstantiated claims, etc. floating around the internet regarding copyright law, and I would hate to see us deleting answers without any actual facts regarding their legality.

Also, there are special exceptions to some copyright laws. The DMCA, for example, allows removal of DRM on ebook files by the visually impaired who need to use text-to-speech technology.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the "take a hard stand" camp and think the answer should be deleted.

The first view is only partially correct, in my view. Information *is* just information, and it is up the reader to decide whether and how to use that information. But -- and this is the key -- this site doesn't have any obligation to make such information available. As I understand it, there is no way to use software for the purposes stated in the answer in question without likely running afoul of an agreement with Amazon. While I'm not offering a legal opinion on this, I will say that I feel quite strongly that we should not encourage or even allow advice like that on this site.